# I want to know if Xamarin forms support watchOS application?

Tags: c#, xamarin, watchos

I made a simple push notification appication(Xamarin Forms) only for iOS. I want to know if I download it on my iPhone am I going to get notifications for iWatch or I need some extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS app made by `Xamarin.forms` is the same as made by `native iOS` when you install the app to your iPhone, they all use the native iOS SDK.

To get notifications from your apple watch:

> Your Apple Watch notifications mirror your iPhone settings, but you
>   can customize the settings for each app. In watchOS 5, notifications
>   can be organized by app and grouped in stacks in Notification Center.
>   For example, all your activity notifications can appear in a stack.
>   You can also choose whether or not you get alerts for notifications,
>   so they appear silently or not at all.

Have a look at this article will help: [Notifications on your Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204791)

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/wiki/Platform-Support
It seems like they don't support watchOS. And there is another project template for watchOS, but there is template for iOS also. I just want to be sure that Xamarin.Forms(Mobile app) supports both and when I start with the tests, the app is going to be downloaded on the watch also, because with the simulator that is not working and app is not installed there or my simulator is bugged.

Comment: @ЗдравкоБоянов The [document is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/watchos/), have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Apple Watch just mirrors notifications of the iPhone by default. You can change this in the settings of the watch or the phone. But if you never touched these, the notifications your iOS App produces should be displayed on the Apple Watch if your phone is locked.

What I wonder though, why didn‘t you just try this out before asking?

Comment: Because I'll have the Apple watch in one week and I wanted to get some information.